# C# using alias for multiple files

Tags: c#

I have defined an alias with `using` like this to shorten my code.

`using MyAction = System.Action<int,int,int,int,string>;`

The problem is this will be used in many files so I have to copy paste them. Is there a way to reuse this?

In only one place : 
`using MyAction = System.Action<int,int,int,int,string>;`

All other places : `using MyAlias.MyAction` or something like this.

Comment: No, that is not possible in C#. It has been requested.

Comment: Cast your support behind https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/259!

Comment: If you need Jon Skeet's answer - https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/745345-using-alias-global-scope (probably there is one on SO, feel free to search)